# How to push some arrays to the main array in angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular7, angular8

Hi i am working on `Angular 7` and I have 3 main arrays fetching from API like mentioned in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yul3dt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

And now the 3 main arrays look like this.

```
 this.mainarr = [
      { id: 1, name: "Praveen", age: 3, color: 3 },
      { id: 2, name: "kumar", age: 2, color: 4 },
      { id: 3, name: "john", age: 4, color: 2 },
      { id: 4, name: "alex", age: 5, color: 1 },
      { id: 5, name: "profes", age: 3, color: 2 }
    ];

    this.agearr = [
      { id: 1, age: 22 },
      { id: 2, age: 24 },
      { id: 3, age: 33 },
      { id: 4, age: 12 },
      { id: 5, age: 26 }
    ];

    this.colorarr = [
      { id: 1, color: "black" },
      { id: 2, color: "paleblack" },
      { id: 3, color: "brown" },
      { id: 4, color: "white" },
      { id: 5, color: "greyish" }
    ];
```

So, in the `mainarr` i have ids and the `agearr` and `colorarr` id matched i need a different key value pair in `mainarr` and display that values.

so my expected result should be

```
[
      { id: 1, name: "Praveen", age: 3, color: 3,agename: 33,colorname: 'brown'},
      { id: 2, name: "kumar", age: 2, color: 4,agename: 24,colorname: 'white'},
      { id: 3, name: "john", age: 4, color: 2 agename: 12,colorname:'paleblack'},
      { id: 4, name: "alex", age: 5, color: 1 agename: 26,colorname:'black'},
      { id: 5, name: "profes", age: 3, color: 2 agename: 33,colorname:'paleblack'}
];
```

I am getting the desired result but only after page refresh how to do it any idea?TIA

Comment: It's likely not relevant, but you state two different Angular versions, which is confusing. I'd also argue that the title is misleading; you're trying to merge object properties based on the `id` property?

Answer (score 0):

Try like following:

```
  getFunction() {
     this.mainarr.map(x => {
        x["agename"] = this.agearr.find(y => y.id == x.age)["age"];
        x["colorname"] = this.colorarr.find(y => y.id == x.color)["color"];
     });
     console.log(this.mainarr);
  }
```

Working `Stackbllitz` Example:  **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ve5cdp?file=src/app/app.component.ts**

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, when i move to the actual code i am getting agename is undefined.

Comment: There what is the key for age

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f4v3gl?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is the updated stackblitz

In the if block you were checking for the wrong property. Corrected it.

```
if (this.mainarr[i].age == this.agearr[j].id)
```

[image]

Comment: Here the problem is i am getting the answer only refreshing the page so any other way to do it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Check the Blitz again. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f4v3gl?file=src/app/app.component.ts I don't understand what you mean by refreshing the page. Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: This looks fine but in my project after ng serve the records are not showing but after refresh records are reflecting.

Comment: That usually means the change detection is not running after the object is updated. Without looking at the code it is impossible to diagnose the issue. Here is a starting point. you can try calling detectChanges on Change Detection Ref. https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular